# Slow boot after logging in (1m 48s)

Tags: boot

I've made the full migration to Linux recently by installing EOS on my main(and only) rig but I've recently noticed it takes about a minute and 48 seconds after timing it once I log in for the dock and panel to show up. I ran dmesg | grep error and got this:

[   13.176596] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   13.855271] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2

Answer (score 1):

Try running these commands

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get full-upgrade

Let the system upgrade everything and then reboot the system. This was addressed recently and is a known bluetooth bug.

source: https://medium.com/elementaryos/loki-updates-for-august-4a6d183364b4

for reference, my computer takes about 40 seconds to load.